# Vuejs 3 - what's the alternative of require.context in vitejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vite

I'm looking for way to make the same logic of `require.context` of webpack in vitejs, I've found this plugin named [vite-plugin-import-context](https://github.com/vbenjs/vite-plugin-import-context), I tried it out but there's something that I didn't understand which is `import dynamicImport from '../src/index'` in the basic usage :

```
import { UserConfigExport } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

import dynamicImport from '../src/index';// <-- this is not described

export default (): UserConfigExport => {
  return {
    plugins: [vue(), dynamicImport(/*options*/)],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

require should never be used in source code when using Vite. It's ESM only.
For Vite v2, `import.meta.globEager` can be used.
For Vite >v2, `import.meta.globEager` is deprecated. Use `import.meta.glob('*', { eager: true })` instead.

Answer (score 2):

import.meta.glob() is webpack alternative of require.context() . It has been added in vite since v2.3.4 .

Here is a link to the doc https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I import all the plugins/modules:

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp(App);

// styles here
import '@/assets/styles/tailwind.css';
import '@/assets/styles/main.scss';

// install all modules under `modules/`
Object.values(
  import.meta.glob<{ install: (ctx: any) => void }>('/src/modules/*.ts', { eager: true })
).forEach((module) => module.install?.(app));

app.mount('#app');
```

and here is how I keep things ready in my `modules` folder to export:

modules/pinia.ts

```
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';

export const install = (app: any) => {
  app.use(createPinia());
};
```

modules/router.ts

```
import type { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router';

import generatedRoutes from '~pages';
import { setupLayouts } from 'virtual:generated-layouts';

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = setupLayouts(generatedRoutes);

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});

export const install = (app: any) => {
  app.use(router);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that example is directly taken from [examples folder in the repo](https://github.com/vbenjs/vite-plugin-import-context/blob/main/examples/vite.config.ts) so it works only in that repo.

If you install the plugin via npm or yarn, the line should look like `import dynamicImport from 'vite-plugin-import-context'`

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
const iconsModule = import.meta.glob('@/path/*.svg');
```

then you can iterate through paths and get the file name with or without format name

```
for (const path in iconsModule) {
            const icon = path.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
            this.icons.push(icon);
        }
```